# how to store the variables in session to transfer it to another page?

Tags: php

I have to give user an email which will contain a link . After clicking on that link user will be redirected to login page first and then to that link to see the comment . My problem is that I don't want to display that ids in URL when user click email link only email id will be displayed in url and rest of ids should in session 
this is form

```
session_start();
$usr=getparams("usr");
$hoss_id=getparams("hoss_id");
$redirect_to_comment=getparams("hotpressContainer");
$_SESSION['hoss_id'] = $hoss_id;
$_SESSION['hotpressContainer'] = $redirect_to_comment;
$select="select email from members where mem_id='$usr'";
$email_id=firesql($select,'get');

if(isset($email_id)){
    $email = $email_id->email;

}else{
        $email = "";      
}

<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" style="border:1px solid #FFFFFF; *width:98%; ">

  <tr>
    <td class="main-text" align="center" >
    <table width="40%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" align="center" class="body">
              <form action="index.php" method="post" name="loginform" onsubmit="return validate()">
              <tr>
                <td width="41%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="59%">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email" size="30" class="iptext" value="'.$email.'"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" size="30" class="iptext"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input name="submit" type="submit" class="submit" value="Continue "></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="referer" value="'.$_SESSION['referer'].'">
                   <input type="hidden" name="pg" value="login" />
                     <input type="hidden" name="d" value="done" />

                </td>
                <td><p><a href="index.php?pg=fp">Forgot Password?</a></p>
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><a href="index.php?pg=register">Join Now</a></td>
              </tr>
        </form>
     </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and on submitting the form user will be redirect to that user my questions are
when I register that varibles in session (in login page ABOVE CODE) that values are not catched in that page where I want to redirect ?

Comment: the tag cakephp in your question, is it error?

Comment: @ sukinsan, just wanted ans. suggestion from cakephp developers

Comment: you wanna get my answer? Do it in the cakephp, and you will get my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to store the variables in session to transfer it to another page?

Assign them to $_SESSION array.

> values are not catched in that page where I want to redirect ?

do you have session_start() on that page?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to start the session again in the top of the second page, before ant html code(if you have any). and store the transferred session to a variable that to hold.

**First page:**

session_start();
...
$_SESSION['hoss_id'] = $hoss_id;

**Second Page:**

session_start();
...
$tempVariable = $_SESSION['hoss_id'];